# How to rebuild typescript app in vs2013 and keep a current web page the same after it

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm trying to rebuild my app in VS2013 than go back to my browser and reloading a page with the app. Despite the same url (including port, for example http://localhost:1883 ) it's unavailable now and I have to run my app once more.

I assume that I should configure **web.config** file

Comment: If you start your app using debugging this cause your problems. Try run app without debugging (ctrl+f5).

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application using `F5` or the play button to start debugging, you need to "Detach All", rather than stop debugging. This will leave the application running.

When you stop debugging, rather than using "Detach All", the application is stopped.

You can also use "Start without debugging" or you can right-click on the HTML file and use "View in browser" to start things up without using the debugger. This will leave the application running until you close Visual Studio.